# QProcess.execute() a DOS command

Tags: c++, qt, command, qprocess

I'am trying to call a DOS command: `subst` with `QProcess` :

```
 QProcess process;
    int returnCode=process.execute(QString("subst " + DLetter+"  "+mountPath));
    qDebug()<<"returnCode"<<returnCode;
    if (returnCode==0){
        qDebug()<<"Mount "<<QString("subst " + DLetter+"  "+mountPath)
                <<"error"<<process.errorString()<<"id"<<process.pid();
        process.waitForFinished();
        ...
    }else
        qDebug()<<" mounting folder failed  "<<process.errorString();
```

My questions are :  Is it enough to call `execute()` and `waitForFinished()`? am I safe with calling execute() instead of start ? because I had issues with `start()` : it didn't work in all cases(it worked for mounting and didn't for dismounting folder) .

Any help wil be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to call cmd directly. Something like: cmd /c subst X: c:\\Test

Comment: @drescherjm I need to execute my command from my application :)

Comment: Put that command in your process.execute instead of what you have.

Comment: yes it is already what I have, `QString("subst " + DLetter+"  "+mountPath)` is the command .

Comment: That was not what I meant. Where is the cmd /c in that command?

Comment: Although forget that. I am wrong. subst is an external command that is in the system32 folder. I forgot and thought it was a builtin to cmd.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of QProcess::execute() at http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qprocess.html#execute

you should do this:

```
int returnCode=process::execute(QString("subst " + DLetter+"  "+mountPath));
qDebug()<<"returnCode"<<returnCode;
if (returnCode==0){
    qDebug()<<"Mount "<<QString("subst " + DLetter+"  "+mountPath)
            <<"error"<<process.errorString()<<"id"<<process.pid();
}else
    qDebug()<<" mounting folder failed  ";
```

The key is QProcess::execute is a static member function that starts the program, waits for it to finish then returns the exit code of the process.

Note: I had to remove the non static calls to process.waitForFinished() and process.errorString() since neither can work from a static QProcess::execute.

Comment: If you want to look at the output of the execution on error you will need to use the non static start. I can look into that. I have done this on windows. Not for subst however for processing and sending medical images which is part of my day job..

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to call a DOS function, try to call it using the

```
#include <process.h>
...
system( "dir c:\\temp > c:\\temp\\output.txt" );
```

but this is now outdated. Try using

```
int nRet= (int)ShellExecute( 0,"open","calc.exe",0,0,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
if ( nRet <= 32 )
{
        DWORD dw= GetLastError(); 
        char szMsg[250];
        FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 
            0, dw, 0,
            szMsg, sizeof(szMsg),
            NULL 
        );
        MessageBox( szMsg, "Error launching Calculator" );
}
```

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx to see how to use this function.

Comment: Thank you for your response.In first place I used  `system()` to call my command but the cmd pop up and disappear and I don't wont that I want to get it silently without this pop up(if there is an option that avoid this , please let me know) so I replace it by `QProcess`, I will try `ShellExecute()` and see .